# Translating arguments into Predicate Logic

Tags: logic

Consider the paragraph given below.

If all the boy friends are either HH or NN, then there are no CC.but Jone is a CC. therefore some boy friends are not NN..

a) translate the following arguments into Predicate Logic

b) using the change of quantifier rule and rules of inference, derive the conclusion

Comment: Take a look at this document: http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/809/ It shows how to emulate Prolog in Mathematica.

Comment: I have seen this [part1](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v4i1/columns/maeder/53-63_Roman41.mj.pdf), [part2](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v4i2/columns/maeder/38-43_maeder42.mj.pdf)

Comment: @happyfish Great resources, but darn, where can I get those floppy disks? :)

Comment: @gwr The code files mentioned at the end of the article can be downloaded [here](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v4i2/esupplement/TMJ-4.2.tar.Z) (in `Columns/Maeder`). You may want to change some function's names, because I remember there are conflicts with currently existing (new) functions.